# Making the content adapt when changing the screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website which needs to be responsive, no problem here as I know how that's being done, but I also need to change the display based on the size of the screen, and this must be done dynamiccly and thus I cannot use media queries (I think).

I'm open to all options: pure css, html, javascript, jQuery, ...

I have a website which looks like the the following:
[image]

This is looking already good, now, when I resize the window to make it smaller, the background will dissapear, and this is achieved based on a CSS3 media query:

```
#OfficeUI { min-height: 52px; background: url('../Images/Application/Backgrounds/Circuit.png') no-repeat scroll right top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: #444; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 0.75em; overflow: hidden; }

@media screen and (max-width: 497px) {

    #OfficeUI { background-image: none; }
}
```

So far, so good, but now the real problem does show up.
When I resize the window to a very small portion of what it is right now, the website does behave like this:

[image]

In this particular case, the text 'Inbox - user...' is moving over the icons. What I would like to have here is that the area of the icons is made smaller, meaning that the most right icon will not be showed anymore. If I further resize the window, the area can shrink again so again an icon is removed.

But the problem here is that I don't have any control over the content which is displayed, there might be 6 icons and there might a very long title, or vice versa.

The only idea I can up with, not implemented in a solution is the following (jQuery):

1. Calculate the width of the Window.
2. Calculate the width of the title area.
3. Calculate the width of the icons area.

On resizing the window, I would implement them something like this:

1. If the size of the icons area and the size of the title area is larger than the window size, then shrink the icons area with a specified amount of pixels (predefined) so that 1 image is removed and repeat that on every resize.

The only problem that I do have with this solution is that the website will grow a lot and performing all those kind of calulcations on every window resize might not be best-practice.

I'm a bit affraid that the website will become very laggy.

**[EDIT]: I've added a snippet with the current code.**

```css
/* General styling that can be applied to all the elements. */
.no-margin { margin: 0px; }
.no-padding { padding: 0px; }

/* General styling for the root of the website. */
#OfficeUI { min-height: 52px; background: url('../Images/Application/Backgrounds/Circuit.png') no-repeat scroll right top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); color: #444; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 0.75em; overflow: hidden; }

/* General styling that can be applied to all kind of elements inside the OfficeUI container. */
#OfficeUI .center { text-align: center; }
#OfficeUI .absolute { position: absolute; }

/* Container elements. */
#OfficeUI .container { display: inline-block; }
#OfficeUI .container-full-width { width: 100%; }

/* Styling for the OfficeUI elements itself. */
#OfficeUI .application-title { margin: 6px 3px 0px 0px; }
#OfficeUI .application-icons img { margin: 3px 1px 0px 4px; }
#OfficeUI .application-icons img:first-child { margin: 3px 0px 0px 7px; }
#OfficeUI .application-icons img:hover:not(:first-child) { background-color: #cde6f7; }

/* Provide some responsive styling. 
   The following styling is applied to the screen when the width of the window is less than 497px. */
@media screen and (max-width: 497px) {
    
    /* Hide the background image when the size of the screen is smaller than the size of the background-image. */
    #OfficeUI { background-image: none; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Defines the main content area for the website. -->
    <body class="no-margin no-padding">
        <!-- Provides the main OfficeUI area. -->
        <div id="OfficeUI">
            
            <!-- Defines the header itself. -->
            <header>
                
                <!-- Provides the area in which the application icons are being showed. -->
                <div class="absolute">
                    <div class="container application-icons">
                        <img src="Resources/Images/Application/Application.png"/>
                        <img src="Resources/Images/Application/Send-Receive.png"/>
                        <img src="Resources/Images/Application/Undo.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Provides the area in which the application title is being rendered. -->
                <div class="container container-full-width center">
                    <div class="application-title">Inbox - user@github.com - Outlook</div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
```

When the window is resized, I would like to see something like:

[image]

Any toughts on this?

Kind regards,

Comment: You could put a white background on the title. the icons will then appear 'behind' that white backround

Comment: You should be able to do all of this with CSS, in this case I think your best option would be to reduce the size of the icons and font size and float right the container with the username or make it span over 2 lines by adding a clear:right on the container for the icons and maybe make each container 100% width for devices under a certain screen width. You can also hide particular icons based on screen size with the media queries.

Comment: What I'm trying is to recreate the Office User Interface, and after this I do have a ribbon which will be far more complex. I really want icon per icon to dissapear. You're still sure about that solution then?

Comment: You could still use CSS for this, I am guessing right now your icon container is of a set width, lets say 20px wide per icon with 5px guttering between each.  At your minimum breakpoint width, why dont you collapse the icon containers width to 25px, therefore only showing the outlook icon, then at another breakpoint you could set the display to none.  There is no need for a jQuery/JS hack here.  Media queries were design to fix these exact problems :)

Comment: Here is a very simple [Example](http://codepen.io/martinjkelly/pen/XJpJoB). You would need to create more accurate rules to make it work exactly as you would expect / want. This just shows one method you could use.

Comment: @Alex Would you mind providing me a small example on how this works? Scriptable Can you double check your example, because the icons are not removed, but stays fixed on the page.

Comment: in my example as you reduce the width of the page it only shows 3 icons and reduces the font size?

Comment: @Scriptable that's correct, but the problem is that I don't know when the resizing should happen. Let's say that there are 7 icons and a very large title. When I resize the window, and the icons and the text cannot be placed on a single line, than the icon area need to be made smaller by 40px. When resizing further and it doesn't fit anymore, the icon area needs to be made smaller by another 40px and so on. In media queries you define the width of the container and that's something what I don't way. No matter what the content is, everything should be placed on a single line, always.

Comment: You need to work within the confines of the space you have available, CSS wont be aware of the length of the content within a container, You need to define overall layout, you may need to use alot of media queries to get what you want, you could use other techniques such as giving the user container a maximum width based on a certain media query and then if any content doesn't fit or is hidden add ... at the end to indicate this. you could reduce the font size instead. By the sounds of what you want and how you want it to behave you'd probably need to use some complex jQuery

Comment: That's exactely what I tought, jQuery to the rescue, but would that make my whole website slow since I will need to do a lot of calculcations based on all the elements on my website. This is just a very small portion of the website.

Comment: Yes, It does seem a bit like your trying to be a bit too exact with this. This is only the header portion of the website and your JS code would be running on all reloads and resizes. You would likely need to use something like Underscores [Debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) or similar functionality to limit execution of the code

Comment: I understand, but I would like to recreate the office ribbon and if you have office installed you should really have a look on how that's behaving when being resized. You'll be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

```
#OfficeUI .application-icons { overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;}


@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    #OfficeUI .application-icons { width: 25px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 250px) {
    #OfficeUI .application-icons { display: none}
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qk1du0wh/

Comment: How would this solve my problem? I don't know at which point the application icons should be resized. See my original question.

Comment: You should create break point to each icon. If you are going to have at most 5 icons, then you should create 5 break points. You can deal with long text by doing the same. Limit its length by `text-overflow`.

Comment: This is not what I need because when I resize, the size of the applications are is shrinked to 25. It must shrink in steps, as soon as the content cannot be placed on a single line anymore.

Comment: I cannot do this because I'm creating a Office User Interface. Throguh the usage of json files, users have the option to show 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on icons. I cannot limit the users to say that only 5 icons are possible. When having a very large title, maybe 1 icons out of 6 is showed, but when the title is very short, all 6 icons can be displayed or even more.